# Can I achieve this with Ztest or Stencil Shaders?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm fairly new with shaders but I wanted to ask about if that idea of mine if possible to achieve through Shaders or not.

I'm doing a dress-up for mobile. I run into problems when I combine for example a blouse/shirt with a jacket, and the blouse is bigger so it pierces the jacket. I know maybe using Cloth element could solve that, but it's super CPU consuming and I'm trying to avoid using it.

I created this abstraction to do some tests. 2 meshes representing 1 blouse (red) and an open blazer. I cannot toggle visibility because in some cases like that, the blazer may be open, so you need to see what's underneath.

[image]

This is what I wanted to achieve:

[image]

I played a little bit with Z test, but I couldn't get what I wanted...

[image]

I also did some stencil tests, but I think I don't know how to use it properly.

[image]

Do you guys have any idea on how to solve that with a shader? Do you think maybe render cue could help??

Thank you for your time.

Comment: ZTest & Stencil will not help, as the red tip is not covered - your 2nd image is as close as you can get. Instead of expensive cloth simulation, you could try relatively cheap mesh slicing. The Jacket could slice the Blouse. You could delete the remainder by checking if it's "outside" of the Jacket (mesh collider maybe?) or simply using a min-size threshold.

Comment: @KYL3R Thank you! I will research about that.